Why does span overlap div?


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  background: red;
}

span {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 200000px 40px;
}
<div>1</div>
<span>2</span>



Can someone please explain me why the span overlaps the div?
Ignore the black top thing; that's just the screenshot from codesandbox
output:


Learn the difference between inline, inline-block and block elements, also research about collapsing margins, and natural stacking. PS what kind of 200000px value is that?

Because padding on inline elements behaves that way. Your span is not getting its dimensions from the width and height you specified (because the span has display: inline by default, so width and height must not have any effect), but only from the padding. And padding-top/-bottom on an inline element doesn't increase the height of the line box it sits in, but extends beyond the box.

As I am seeing your code you have given margin: 200000px 40px; so here you are setting 200000px from top and bottom and 40px from left and right. Setting such an inapproriate margin for top and bottom can cause this unusual behaviour
This margin effectively pushes the span element far down the page, creating a large empty space above and below it.
Try setting some appropriate value for margin to get desired result.

The margin has little to do with this. You can remove it completely, and the only thing that will change, is that the span starts at the very left, instead of 40px from the left.
